# Renaming incrementing integer name to incrementing integer

Tags: powershell, batch-file

can you show me a way to solve following problem with **Powershell** or **CMD**?

This is my file names in folder.

```
002.mp3
003.mp3
.
.
.
604.mp3
```

I want to change that numbers to;

```
001.mp3
002.mp3
003.mp3
.
.
.
603.mp3
```

But important thing is, it has to be like that

```
002.mp3 to 001.mp3
003.mp3 to 002.mp3
...
...
...
604.mp3 to 603.mp3
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PathToMP3Files\[0-6][0-9][0-9].mp3" -File
$files | Rename-Item -NewName {"{0:D3}.mp3" -f ([int]$_.BaseName - 1)} -whatif
```

Just remove the `-whatif` parameter to perform the rename if you are satisfied with the results.

**Explanation:**

The `-Path` parameter of [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) supports wildcards. Using a wildcard range `[0-6]` (one character from the set 0 to 6), you can narrow down your target items.

Since [New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7)'s `-NewName` supports delay-script binding, you can pipe your `FileInfo` objects directly into the command. The `-NewName` parameter manipulates the `Name` property of the object. The code above is using `BaseName`, which is the `Name` without the extension, because it is an easy way to perform digit increase.

`-f` is the string format operator. It performs a substitution of `{number}` values within a string. The number corresponds to an item's index in the collection provided to the right of the `-f`.

Comment: you saved my day. have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler in a Batch file, and run faster than PS too! (just try it)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('dir /B *.mp3') do set /A "n=1%%~Na-1" & ren "%%a" "!n:~1!.mp3"
```

Yoy may even do it directly at the command prompt with no need of a .bat file; just be sure that `n` variable does not exists (executing `set "n="` before):

```
for /F %a in ('dir /B *.mp3') do @set /A "n=1%~Na-1" & call ren "%a" "%n:~1%.mp3"
```